# Object required error. How to search for a dimensioned variable?

Tags: vba, variables, object, range

I am getting an "Run-time error '424': Object Required" error when running a macro (I didn't write it) and this is the line that is highlighted when debugging:

```
Set fc = r.Cells(r.Range("folder_contents").Row, r.Range("folder_contents").Column)
```

So I'm thinking I need to trace where "r" was defined because I know where the "folder_contents" range is located in the active sheet.

To this end, I have tried searching the entire project for "Dim r", "r = ", "Set r" and just simply " r". I couldn't find anything anywhere.

First of all, am I on the right track in trying to find what "r" is? Or is it a different problem.

I have another version of the same workbook where the macros work. I don't know the differences between them, but they are similar enough to compare. So it doesn't make sense why one works and the other doesn't.

Comment: Add `Option Explicit` to the top of every code module it it's not already there: if you then try to compile the VBA Project it will tell you which variables are being used but have not been declared. While debugging, you can open the locals window and see the values for any in-scope variable

Comment: Thanks, Tim Williams. Just as I suspected, I now get an error saying that the variable "r" is not defined. If "r" was defined, how does one find out where exactly in the modules it is defined? What or how do you search for?

Comment: It's actually pretty easy - right-click on the variable name and choose "Definition" from the pop-up menu.  If it hasn't been declared you'll get -
"Identifier under cursor is not recognized"